# right not working but left is at position: absolute;

Tags: html, css, css-position

```css
.act{
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

/* arrows*/
.left_arrow{
    top: calc(117.2% + 12.75vh);
    left: 19%;
    transform: rotateZ(90deg);
}

.right_arrow{ 
    top: calc(117.2% + 12.75vh);
    right: 19%;
    transform: rotateZ(-90deg);
}

.act img{
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="act">
            <img src="./landingPage/down arrow black.png" alt="left arrow" class="left_arrow">
            <img src="./landingPage/down arrow black.png" alt="right arrow" class="right_arrow">
</div>
```

The 'right: 19%;' at the .right_arrow is not working but 'left' is working at the .left_arrow .

Anyone knows why?

Comment: both right and left seems to work properly in your demo, you can toggle those values and check in browser

Comment: can you describe *no working* and also include the images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `position:relative;` to `.act` class and it should work

the `position:absolute;` on the `img` element looks for a container to position itself against, this container has to have x, y, height and width values inside the DOM. giving the parent element (in this case `.act`) `position:relative;` ensures the element has a x, y, width and a height onto with the `img` elements can be placed

Comment: Why does this work? Please edit your answer and explain this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@j.xiang,

I highly recommend that you read: [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning) regarding positioning. To answer your question on why your code isn't working and why:

> An absolutely positioned element no longer exists in the normal
>   document layout flow. Instead, it sits on its own layer separate from
>   everything else. This is very useful: it means that we can create
>   isolated UI features that don't interfere with the position of other
>   elements on the page.  For example, popup information boxes and
>   control menus; rollover panels; UI features that can be dragged and
>   dropped anywhere on the page; and so on...
>
> Second, notice that the position of the element has changed — this is
>   because top, bottom, left, and right behave in a different way with
>   absolute positioning. Instead of specifying the direction the element
>   should move in, they specify the distance the element should be from
>   each containing element's sides. So in this case, we are saying that
>   the absolutely positioned element should sit 30px from the top of the
>   "containing element", and 30px from the left.

Now you may have already been familiar with the above statement, which brings us to why and the positioning context.

> If no ancestor elements have their position property explicitly
>   defined, then by default all ancestor elements will have a static
>   position. The result of this is, the absolutely positioned element
>   will be contained in the initial containing block. The initial
>   containing block has the dimensions of the viewport and is also the
>   block that contains the  element. Simply put, the absolutely
>   positioned element will be contained outside of the  element,
>   and be positioned relative to the initial viewport.
>
> The positioned element is nested inside the  in the HTML source,
>   but in the final layout, it is 30px away from the top and left of the
>   edge of the page. We can change the positioning context — which
>   element the absolutely positioned element is positioned relative to.
>   This is done by setting positioning on one of the element's ancestors
>   — to one of the elements it is nested inside (you can't position it
>   relative to an element it is not nested inside). To demonstrate this,
>   add the following declaration to your body rule:

```
   position: relative;
```

So adding `position: relative;` to your `.act` class should fix your specific problem.

I hope this helps, again start your reading on the [MDN site](https://developer.mozilla.org) it's an invaluable resource.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had left propety set in another css class thats why the right wasn't applied, I added
left:unset;

and then the right was applied